# Matrix diagonalisation, and orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey I have a a question on how to diagonalize matrices. My lecture focuses on symmetric matrices, but I have examples where I need to calculate $D$ for non- symmetric matrices as well.

I know that I can simply but in the Eigenvalues into $D$ if $D$ exists. But if I would like to calculate $D$ by hand with

$$D= U^{-1}AU$$

I found that i sometimes have to orthogonalize the vectors of U and normalize them and sometimes not.

I cant seem to find a pattern, and I cant find anything online. Maybe I am just completely wrong, this topic is new to me.... so please excuse if the question is stupid ....

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general we have that if we can find a basis of eigenvectors we can always [**diagonalize a matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Characterization) and

- $D$ contains the eigenvalues along the diagonal
- $U$ contains the corresponding eigenvectors by columns

such that

$$AU=UD \iff U^{-1}AU=D $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where i am uncleared about is when I have to orthogonalize U ....

Comment: @Lillys Not always we can do that. We can of course when A is symmetric otherwise we cannot do that and in these case we need to take $U^{-1}$ to express $A$ in the form $A=UDU^{-1}$.

Comment: I hope it is ok if i as so many questions. Ím not sure if I’m using the right words, as i cant find them in any dictonary and ím not studying in English, what i know that wie have to use u^-1, i corrected that above, what i meant with orthogonalize is to treat the vectors in u such that the dot product of each is 0 - meaning they are perpendicular.

Comment: @Lillys You need to refer to [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem): If A is symmetric, there exists an orthonormal basis of V consisting of eigenvectors of A. Each eigenvalue is real.